# sql load data local infile not finding file

Tags: mysql

I have checked apparmor and gave permissions to the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/.../toUpload.txt' INTO TABLE table_name (value0,value1,value2);
```

will return:

```
ERROR 2 (HY000): File '/.../toUpload.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

I am running on an aws with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Did you give permission to the right user? MySQL usually runs with its own user name.

Comment: As it stands, no one can answer your question, because whatever is causing your problem is not mentioned in your post. Can you print out and post the permissions of apparmor? (I don't use it, so IDK.)

Comment: @jpaugh In ubuntu apparmor is an application that ships with ubuntu 14.04 and prevents mysql from reading/writing to directories for safety concerns, I put the files I am working on in the exclusion for it and the requests don't come up in the log for apparmor. When I said permission I gave ownership of the file to the mysql user.

Comment: Ok. I know what apparmor is, but I've never used it (or SELinux). I was merely pointing out that any answers must of necessity be guesses. (Some of them perhaps very educated guesses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely correct.

You're right; it turns out that for whatever well-intentioned reason this flavor of mysql doesn't by default allow loading from a local infile.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/toUpload.txt' INTO TABLE table_name;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
mysql>


monte@oobun2:~$ mysql -h localhost -u monte -p monte --local-infile
Enter password: 

...

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/toUpload.txt' INTO TABLE table_name;
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 8  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name;
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| name     | owner  | species | sex  | birth      | death      |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
| Fluffy   | Harold | cat     | f    | 1993-02-04 | NULL       |
| Claws    | Gwen   | cat     | m    | 1994-03-17 | NULL       |
| Buffy    | Harold | dog     | f    | 1989-05-13 | NULL       |
| Fang     | Benny  | dog     | m    | 1990-08-27 | NULL       |
| Bowser   | Diane  | dog     | m    | 1979-08-31 | 1995-07-29 |
| Chirpy   | Gwen   | bird    | f    | 1998-09-11 | NULL       |
| Whistler | Gwen   | bird    | NULL | 1997-12-09 | NULL       |
| Slim     | Benny  | snake   | m    | 1996-04-29 | NULL       |
| Puffball | Diane  | hamster | f    | 1999-03-30 | NULL       |
+----------+--------+---------+------+------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

keep your file in /tmp folder and try same command, it will work as mysql user should have rights to read file from source directory.

Comment: This would work as a sanity check, but it's obviously not a permanent solution, since `/tmp` gets overwritten by the OS on reboot, and it is general practice to freely delete items in the `/tmp` folder.

Comment: dear @jpaugh, which file ,we are going to upload also a temp file and to keep such type temp file in data directory is also not a good idea. as you have proivded -ve rating, so may you explain little bit what is drawback to upload data to keep file in /tmp folder.

Comment: The OP never suggested that the file was a temp file. (and might not want to delete it, even if the current operation is "temporary") And, some newbie Linux user might come by and not realize that /tmp is special. It's not a robust solution. I think a "Quick fix" is fine, but you should at least warn the unwary.